# Eclipse Android Checkbox

Tags: android, eclipse, checkbox, onclick

I would like to create checkbox with text that would behave something like what i have below in pseudo code:

```
Set in text in EditText field
if Button clicked:
    create new Checkbox  with entered text.
```

How do i go about doing that in Android?
So far ive got the button :) ... but dont know how to get new Checkbox with text in it ,if its clicked

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    Button create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    create.setOnClickListener(this);
    EditText textInCheckBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Automatisch generierter Methodenstub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        //after creating new checkbox with text in it 
        //Editbox should restet text field to null;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that will demonstrate how to add checkboxes dynamically with the title you entered into the EditText.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        final Button btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        final RadioGroup radContainer = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radContainer);

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = txtTitle.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!name.isEmpty()) {

                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);
                    checkBox.setText(name);
                    checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);

                    radContainer.addView(checkBox);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a title for the checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Checkbox" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```